# Как сохранить вложенную запись из JSON в SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, retrofit2

Я получаю данные в таком виде:

```
{
    "duration": 5,
    "intervals": 60,
    "time_work_start": 540,
    "time_work_end": 1080,
    "lunch_start": 780,
    "lunch_end": 840,
    "workweek": {
        "1": "Понедельник",
        "2": "Вторник"
    },
    "time_delay": 15
}
```

Тело запроса выглядит так:

```
public class BodyUserSettings implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("duration")
@Expose
private String duration;
@SerializedName("intervals")
@Expose
private String intervals;
@SerializedName("time_work_start")
@Expose
private String timeWorkStart;
@SerializedName("time_work_end")
@Expose
private String timeWorkEnd;
@SerializedName("lunch_start")
@Expose
private String lunchStart;
@SerializedName("lunch_end")
@Expose
private String lunchEnd;
@SerializedName("workweek")
@Expose
private Workweek workweek;
@SerializedName("time_delay")
@Expose
private String timeDelay;

public String getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(String duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public BodyUserSettings withDuration(String duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
    return this;
}

public String getIntervals() {
    return intervals;
}

public void setIntervals(String intervals) {
    this.intervals = intervals;
}

public BodyUserSettings withIntervals(String intervals) {
    this.intervals = intervals;
    return this;
}

public String getTimeWorkStart() {
    return timeWorkStart;
}

public void setTimeWorkStart(String timeWorkStart) {
    this.timeWorkStart = timeWorkStart;
}

public BodyUserSettings withTimeWorkStart(String timeWorkStart) {
    this.timeWorkStart = timeWorkStart;
    return this;
}

public String getTimeWorkEnd() {
    return timeWorkEnd;
}

public void setTimeWorkEnd(String timeWorkEnd) {
    this.timeWorkEnd = timeWorkEnd;
}

public BodyUserSettings withTimeWorkEnd(String timeWorkEnd) {
    this.timeWorkEnd = timeWorkEnd;
    return this;
}

public String getLunchStart() {
    return lunchStart;
}

public void setLunchStart(String lunchStart) {
    this.lunchStart = lunchStart;
}

public BodyUserSettings withLunchStart(String lunchStart) {
    this.lunchStart = lunchStart;
    return this;
}

public String getLunchEnd() {
    return lunchEnd;
}

public void setLunchEnd(String lunchEnd) {
    this.lunchEnd = lunchEnd;
}

public BodyUserSettings withLunchEnd(String lunchEnd) {
    this.lunchEnd = lunchEnd;
    return this;
}

public Workweek getWorkweek() {
    return workweek;
}

public void setWorkweek(Workweek workweek) {
    this.workweek = workweek;
}

public BodyUserSettings withWorkweek(Workweek workweek) {
    this.workweek = workweek;
    return this;
}

public String getTimeDelay() {
    return timeDelay;
}

public void setTimeDelay(String timeDelay) {
    this.timeDelay = timeDelay;
}

public BodyUserSettings withTimeDelay(String timeDelay) {
    this.timeDelay = timeDelay;
    return this;
}

public class Workweek implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("1")
    @Expose
    private String _1;
    @SerializedName("2")
    @Expose
    private String _2;

    public Workweek(String _1, String _2) {
        super();
        this._1 = _1;
        this._2 = _2;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return _1;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this._1 = id;
    }

    public Workweek withId(String _1) {
        this._1 = _1;
        return this;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return _2;
    }

    public void setTitle(String _2) {
        this._2 = _2;
    }

    public Workweek withTitle(String _2) {
        this._2 = _2;
        return this;
    }
}
```

}

POST-запрос:

```
@POST("/settings")
Call<BodyUserSettings> postIdToken(@Body BodyIdToken id_token);
```

В mainactivity:

```
 private void sendRequestIdTokenToServer() {
    BodyIdToken hexPost = new BodyIdToken();
    hexPost.idToken = mIdToken;
    Call<BodyUserSettings> call = mService.postIdToken(hexPost);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<BodyUserSettings>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<BodyUserSettings> call, @NonNull Response<BodyUserSettings> response) {
            mBodyUserSettings = response.body();
            mMainDatabase.saveSettings(mBodyUserSettings);
            mMainDatabase.saveWorkweekDays(mBodyWorkweek);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<BodyUserSettings> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Таблицы в SQLite:

```
private final String CREATE_SETTINGS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            SETTINGS_TABLE + "(" +
            _id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            DURATION + "INTEGER," +
            INTERVALS + " INTEGER," +
            TIME_WORK_START + " INTEGER," +
            TIME_WORK_END + " INTEGER," +
            LAUNCH_START + " INTEGER," +
            LAUNCH_END + " INTEGER," +
            WORKWEEK + " INTEGER," +
            TIME_DELAY + " INTEGER" + ")";

    private final String CREATE_WORKWEEK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            WORKWEEK_TABLE + "(" +
            _id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            ID_DAY + " TEXT," +
            TITLE_DAY + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Сохранение в SQLite

```
public void saveSettings(BodyUserSettings settings) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(DURATION, settings.getDuration());
    cv.put(INTERVALS, settings.getIntervals());
    cv.put(TIME_WORK_START, settings.getTimeWorkStart());
    cv.put(TIME_WORK_END, settings.getTimeWorkEnd());
    cv.put(LAUNCH_START, settings.getLunchStart());
    cv.put(LAUNCH_END, settings.getLunchEnd());
    cv.put(WORKWEEK, String.valueOf(settings.getWorkweek()));
    cv.put(TIME_DELAY, settings.getTimeDelay());

    db.insert(SETTINGS_TABLE, null, cv);
    Log.d("LOG_TAG_saveSettings ", "save: " +
            settings.getDuration() + "; " +
            settings.getIntervals() + "; " +
            settings.getTimeWorkStart() + "; " +
            settings.getTimeWorkEnd() + "; " +
            settings.getLunchStart() + "; " +
            settings.getLunchEnd() + "; " +
            settings.getWorkweek() + "; " +
            settings.getTimeDelay() + ".");
    db.close();
}

public void saveWorkweekDays(BodyUserSettings.Workweek workweek) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(ID_DAY, workweek.getId());
    cv.put(TITLE_DAY, workweek.getTitle());

    db.insert(WORKWEEK_TABLE, null, cv);
    Log.d("LOG_TAG_saveWorkweek", "save " +
            workweek.getId() + "; " +
            workweek.getTitle() + ".");
    db.close();
}
```

}

И в итоге я получаю данные в таком виде:

D/LOG_TAG_saveSettings: save: 5; 60; 540; 1080; 780; 840; com.example.myApp.data.network.entities.BodyUserSettings$Workweek@3ed84f07; 15.

Не пойму, как мне корректно отобразить данные из workweek. Может они вообще неправильно сохраняются. Что я делаю не так?

Если использовать парсинг JSON, то как потом это сохранить в SQLite?

Comment: Может вам нужно в `public class Workweek` переопределить метод `toString()`?

Comment: и в `sendRequestIdTokenToServer` мне почему то кажется что нужно для начало сохранять `mMainDatabase.saveWorkweekDays(mBodyWorkweek);`

Comment: Для начала нужно понять, что в логах Вы видите не данные, а текстовое представление объекта. Чтобы видеть что-то более информативное нужно переопределить `toString()` или писать в лог содержимое полей.

Comment: Пока что ничего из этого не помогло...

Comment: А если использовать парсинг JSON, то как потом workweek сохранить в SQLite?

Comment: Так у Вас уже всё сделано: и `json` спарсен, и данные из него в базу записаны. А чтобы узнать правильно ли они записаны нужно уже делать выборку из базы и куда-нибудь выводить.